# list git lfs lockable files

Tags: git, locking, git-lfs

With git lfs it is possible to register a file type as lockable, without using LFS. From the lfs [wiki page](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/wiki/File-Locking):

> If you'd like to register a file type as lockable, without using LFS,
>   you can edit the .gitattributes file directly:
>
> `*.yml lockable`
>
> Once file patterns in .gitattributes are lockable, Git LFS will make
>   them readonly on the local file system automatically. This prevents
>   users from accidentally editing a file without locking it first.

I would like to do this for *.sql files, but when I do this, and run

```
git lfs ls-files
```

sql files are not returned.

Is there a way to `ls-files` that can be locked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git LFS doesn't provide a built-in way to do this. However, you can ask Git to do this for you by using `git check-attr`:

```
git ls-files | git check-attr --stdin lockable | awk -F': ' '$3 ~ /set/ { print $1 }'
```

This prints all files in the repository with the `lockable` attribute set.